# Airflow 1.9.0 failing to queue tasks

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I'm having an issue where tasks will successfully finish, but the downstream task will not recognize that fact, and so will not be queued.

Exhibit A: Task is successful

[image: Task says success]

Exhibit B: `stage_photos` is not being queued:

[image]

Is this a known issue? Anyone have any advice? This seems to have started with the upgrade from 1.8 to 1.9, and also only for certain kinds of tasks (sensors, python operators that return values).

Comment: What's the status of the same two tasks in the run prior to the once pictured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you have multiple runs of the DAG that have not succeeded which is why it isn't working with the `depends_on_past` set to True.

From the official [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules): `depends_on_past` (boolean) that, when set to True, keeps a task from getting triggered if the previous schedule for the task hasn’t succeeded.

If according to my guess, a previous run has not reached it's end state with the `stage_photos` having succeeded in that previous run, this will not work in the current run.

Comment: That's interesting - my understanding was that `depends_on_past` just meant that it would depend on previous tasks in the run, not previous schedules. Any idea how to kickstart this back into working again? I've tried manually failing/deleting previous runs

Comment: Manually marking previous runs as success should do the trick.

Comment: THANK YOU. This worked. Now I just have to backill for a all the days this was broken...